# How to remove lib-font-face from Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, less, less-css, fonts

I've created a theme in ***Magento2*** which inherits from the ***Luma*** theme.  So it has inherited it's `lib-font-face`, which can be found in the `styles-m.css`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'luma-icons';
  src: url('../fonts/Luma-Icons.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/Luma-Icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Luma-Icons.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/Luma-Icons.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Luma-Icons.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/Luma-Icons.svg#luma-icons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I don't want to use these, so it's pointless HTTP request.

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that are defined in:
lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_typography.less

The guys at ClassyLama have a great article on it here:
https://www.classyllama.com/blog/icon-fonts-magento-2-foundation

Comment: Thanks! How did you completly remove the default Luma-Icons font?

Answer (score 0):

To remove `Luma-Icons` put this in your theme's `default_head_blocks.xml`:

```
<remove src="fonts/Luma-Icons.woff2" />
```

If you don't use OpenSans anywhere you can also put this in the file:

```
<remove src="fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff2" />
<remove src="fonts/opensans/regular/opensans-400.woff2" />
<remove src="fonts/opensans/semibold/opensans-600.woff2" />
<remove src="fonts/opensans/bold/opensans-700.woff2" />
```

Then just clear the layout cache: `bin/magento cache:clean layout`

Comment: Still working perfectly as of Magento CE 2.4.6, thanks!